# Connection Refused after Changing Apache DocumentRoot on OS X El Capitan

Tags: apache

I am using OS X El Capitan, and changed the Apache2 config file /etc/apache2/http.conf to relocate the file path.

I modified 
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents" 
to 
    DocumentRoot "~/Dropbox/myweb", and

```
<Directory "Library/WebServer/Documents">
```

to

```
<Directory "~/Dropbox/myweb">.
```

Directory content is

```
Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
MultiviewsMatch Any
AllowOverride None
Require all granted
```

and changed the folder like

```
sudo chmod 777 ~/Dropbox/myweb
```

I restarted Apache then I cannot connect to http://localhost anymore. Opera returns me

```
Opera's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
```

Chrome returns me

```
This webpage is not available
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I am not sure if I missed any step?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `apachectl configtest` to figure if your configurations are all OK. Got the same problem here and configtest told me something was wrong in httpd-userdir.conf file.

Comment: My configtest says `Syntax OK`... Any other ideas?